# Imported subprocess while using Popen.pid but error is pid is not attribute of Popen

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have been learning about the subprocess module, my code is:

```
import subprocess,time,sys
from subprocess import Popen

p = subprocess.Popen('start http-server', shell=True)
time.sleep(1)
pp = Popen.pid
print(pp)
```

The error is `pid is not defined`, but as per Python documentation I think `Popen.pid` is the correct syntax.

I am trying to get the pid of the command window that was opened by

```
subprocess.Popen('start http-server',shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By running `pp = Popen.pid`, you are trying to access the `pid` (so an attribute) of the `Popen` class ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects)). The class itself, not an object (instance) of that class!

What you meant to do is access the attribute `pid` of an *object* of class `Popen`. You created this object with `p = subprocess.Popen(...)`. Thus you can access its `pid` with:

```
pp = p.pid
```